# Why is a virtual function of child class not called

Tags: c++, arduino

I have a base and a derived class:

**plugin.h**

```
#ifndef PLUGIN_H
#define PLUGIN_H

// plugin states
#define PLUGIN_IDLE 0

class Plugin {
public:
  Plugin();
  ~Plugin();

  virtual void loop();
};

#endif
```

**plugin.cpp**

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "plugin.h"

Plugin::Plugin() {
}

Plugin::~Plugin(){
}

void Plugin::loop(){
  Serial.println("Plugin::loop()");
}
```

**derived class**

```
class OneWirePlugin : public Plugin {
public:
  OneWirePlugin(byte pin);
  void loop();
};

OneWirePlugin::OneWirePlugin(byte pin) {
}

void OneWirePlugin::loop() {
  Serial.println("OneWirePlugin::loop()");
}
```

I was expecting that calling the derived instance's `loop()` method would execute `OneWirePlugin::loop()`.

However, this *only* happens when I call it in derived class context:

```
Plugin p = Plugin();
Plugin o = OneWirePlugin(ONEWIRE_PIN);
OneWirePlugin q = OneWirePlugin(ONEWIRE_PIN);
p.loop(); // Plugin::loop()
o.loop(); // Plugin::loop()
q.loop(); // OneWirePlugin::loop()
```

What's wrong with my virtual method that will allow be calling the derived implementation, especially when referenced via `*Plugin` pointers?

Comment: There is no `virtual` function declared in `plugin`??

Comment: Also beware of [slicing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)

Comment: You probably need to realize C++ is not Java.

Comment: To all -1 voters: I've mentioned that I've tested with virtual as well which was not helping due ti the slicing. So please stop it if reading is too much of a burden...

Comment: I've updated the question to highlight that slicing was causing the issue.

Comment: Please don't put tags in question's title - it's against SO policy. They are prepended automatically and quite visible, so there is no need for that :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`loop` must be declared as `virtual`:

```
class Plugin {

// ...

virtual void loop();
```

Also, for the polymorphism to work, you need a pointer or a reference:

```
Plugin* o = new OneWirePlugin(ONEWIRE_PIN);
o->loop();

// ...

delete o;
```

<sup>(in your code, [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) occurs, as noted by [Mat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/635608/mat) in the comments section)</sup>

And then, consider using smart pointers (like `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`).

---

If you're using C++11 you should also mark `loop` with the `override` specifier in subclasses:

```
class OneWirePlugin : public Plugin {

// ...

void loop() override {
```

Comment: `make_unique` is no better than `new`.

Comment: @SergeyA Slightly better, because you don't need `delete`.

Comment: can you please elaborate? I am not following this.

Comment: @SergeyA Elaborate on what? Perhaps I've misunderstood your comment.

Comment: @SergeyA Missing `delete` in various situations (e.g. exceptions thrown) is a common error when hand coding `new`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, BartoszKP, someone is missing something there. My comment was only related to 'consider not using new directly, but switching to unique_ptr or shared_ptr' - and I meant to say, there is nothing wrong with using `unique_ptr` and `new` together  - I know some ppl advocate for `make_unique` instead of `new`, but I do not see any benefits..

Comment: @SergeyA OK, now I understand. I was not aware of this controversy, so I'm grateful that you've mentioned it. However, this question seems to set a context that is too basic for this kind of discussion. The point of this part of my answer was only to encourage smart pointers, nothing more :)

Comment: Arduino does not allow C++11 yet through the IDE.

Comment: @andig At least there is `std::auto_ptr<>` for pre C++11 code. It's still better than using a raw pointer.

Comment: @andig Since version 1.5.7 you can enable C++11, and 1.6.6 and above have it enabled by default. However there is no standard library support, so no auto/shared/unique pointers.

Answer (score 0):

In your question - 
1. Plugin p = new Plugin();
2. Plugin o = OneWirePlugin(ONEWIRE_PIN);

1. will call Plugin::loop() as it base class object .
2. will also call Plugin::loop() as you are creating Plugin object and this way object slicing occurs to form base class object from derived class object .

Below example will help .

```
class Base { int x, y; };

class Derived : public Base { int z, w; };

int main() 
{
    Derived d;
    Base b = d; // Object Slicing,  z and w of d are sliced off
}
```

Run on IDE
Object slicing happens when a derived class object is assigned to a base class object, additional attributes of a derived class object are sliced off to form the base class object.